# In chrome my pictures height changes

Tags: css

I have created one big picture that contains 4 smaller pictures.

My 4 pictures all have an height of 425.5px. In Firefox it looks great, however in Chrome there becomes an gap between the 4 pictures so you can see some of the big picture behind them.

It looks like the height of my 4 pictures becomes a little smaller in google chrome, without the bigger picture does.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
img { 
   display: block;
}
```

And please please please don't use 425.5px (half a pixel)...

Comment: It did change it, however now everything in chrome is a little too tall now.